# Why is my Fragments not hidden when I set the hide/show

Tags: android, android-fragments

**UPDATE** **added my own answer since I solved it. The question is untouched look at answer!**

I was following this [Navigation View - Material Design Support Library Tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html). I made some changes so that i could hide and show the `Fragments`. The `Fragment` will synk against FireBase so I want them to be alive and well, and not constantly recreated. The problem is that I can never make them hide. I clearly see in the **LogCat** that `Fragment` `onAttach()`, with is a requirement for show/hide to work right??
What am I completely missing here?

Adding some code first AppCompatActivity

```
/**
 * Main launcher
 */
public class FragmentActivityMain extends ManagedAppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener,
        ConfirmDialogListener, NotificationDialogListener, OnConnectionStateListener,
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = FragmentActivityMain.class.getName();
............
```

This is the TypedArray holding NavigationView menu items(Fragments)

```
    <!-- NavigationView items -->
    <string-array name="navigationview_items">
        <item>com.port.android.ui.HomeFragment</item>
        <item>com.port.android.ui.ChatFragment</item>
        <item>com.port.android.ui.BillboardFragment</item>
        <item>com.port.android.ui.NewsFragment</item>
        <item>com.port.android.ui.settingsFragment</item>
        <item>com.port.android.ui.LoginFragment</item>
    </string-array>
```

Loading the TypedArray

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
navigationviewItems = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navigationview_items);

}
```

The onNavigationItemSelected listener that will check if the Fragment is added to the supportFragmentManager and if not adding it

```
    // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    String tag;
    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    View r = findViewById(R.id.landing_page);
    //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home: // HomeFragment
            tag = navigationviewItems.getString(0);
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
                try {
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, (Fragment) Class.forName(tag).newInstance(), tag)
                            .addToBackStack(tag)
                            .commit();
                    MyLog.i(TAG, "Class.forName(tag) = " + tag);
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else
                MyLog.i(TAG, "switch SHOW " + tag);
            hideAllFrags(tag);
            return true;
        case R.id.chat: // ChatFragment
            tag = navigationviewItems.getString(1);
            ....................
```

When the above onNavigationItemSelected has selected the Fragment to be visible this method should hide all Fragments except @param fragment.

```
/**
 * Hide all Fragments except @param fragment
 */
private void hideAllFrags(String fragment) {
    for (int index = 0; index < navigationviewItems.length(); index++)
        try {
            if (!fragment.equals(navigationviewItems.getString(index))) {
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment) != null)
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment)).commit();
                Log.d(TAG, "HIDING " + navigationviewItems.getString(index));
            }else{
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment) != null)
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment)).commit();
                Log.d(TAG, "SHOWING " + navigationviewItems.getString(index));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CANNOT LOAD navigationviewItems " + navigationviewItems.getString(index));
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
}
```

[This is what it looks like and both the chat and the home fragment are visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdFNC.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you work with `replace`?

Comment: I think `replace` will make the `Fragment` go to `onDetach()`, I dont want that

Comment: Why? If you don't want to reload the `Fragment` everytime you show it (with `replace()`, you simply need to store an instance of it in your `Activity`, and reuse it.

Comment: @Amylinn Yes your right but I wanted to try to do it by the book, so to speak, hide/show

Answer (score 0):

ok it was my mistake after a night with bad coffee.

If you need to you can replace with this working code, note also that I added the the `executePendingTransactions()` to make transaction happen immediately.

```
/**
 * Hide all Fragments except @param fragment
 */
private void hideAllFrags(String fragment) {
    String name = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < navigationviewItems.length(); index++)
        try {
            name = navigationviewItems.getString(index);
            if (!fragment.equals(name)) {
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name) != null) {
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name)).commit();
                    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "HIDING " + name);
            } else {
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment) != null) {
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment)).commit();
                    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "SHOWING " + fragment);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CANNOT LOAD navigationviewItems " + fragment);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
}
```

adding `executePendingTransactions()`..and the `addToBackStack(null)` is optional. I think user is used to be able to press back button and expect to travel back in view histori.

```
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home: // HomeFragment
                tag = navigationviewItems.getString(0);
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
                    try {
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, (Fragment) Class.forName(tag).newInstance(), tag)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
                        MyLog.i(TAG, "Class.forName(tag) = " + tag);
...............
```